# Redis: sort command is returning strings with ascent wrongly ordered

Tags: sorting, redis, diacritics

I am making use of Nodejs and Redis set to store strings that are in German and contains **Umlauts**. Here is the code:

```
const client = redis.createClient();
const asyncClient = promisify(client.sort).bind(client);

async function printResponse(){
  console.log(await asyncClient("search","alpha"))
}

printResponse();
```

Here is the response I am getting as a result of sort operation:

```
[
  'Einflüssen',    'Jüpïtër',  
  'Möglichkeiten', 'Mǟrs',     
  'Schön',         'Sǟtürn',   
  'Versalhöhe',    'Vënüs',    
  'großzügiger',   'größte',   
  'lästigen',      'stören',   
  'Ëarth',         'Überblick',
  'öffentlichen'
]
```

Above result is sorted alphabetically upto String "Vënüs" or can be said it is not sorted properly. Can strings with ascents/umlauts be sorted correctly with the *sort-alpha* or there is another way to sort umlauts?

Answer (score 0):

According the the documentation of the [SORT](https://redis.io/commands/sort) command, you can set the LC_COLLATE environment variable to sort correctly for your particular locale. This needs to happen on the server Redis is running on. I've not tried this, but this is the direction I would look to solve the problem.

If that doesn't work, you'll need to sort it correctly in your code.